# show/hide the tabbar when needed from a view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

i am new to iOS programming. i really need your help.

i have a login screen that takes me to a map (google API). on clicking any created annotation i want to load a tabbar with 2 views.

i searched and found out that i need to add the tabbar at the starting ie the appdelegate and show/hide the tabbar when needed.

so i made 2 functions to show and hide tabbar as

```
-(void)Load_tabBar{
[self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyWindow];}

-(void)remove_tabBar{
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;
[self.tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyWindow];}
```

it did work when i call the Load_tabBar method and when i click back it calls remove_tabBar method. if i again call Load_tabBar method and back, it crashes giving error

-[UILayoutContainerView window]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x563b0b0

edited: PS : can i add tabbar view to a view controller and then push that view?

thnx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this    `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`

Comment: can i add tabbar view to a view controller and then push that view?

Comment: when you are pushing the view controller in that presenting view controller you have to add this in viewWillAppear method.No need to use your code

Comment: Preferably use this in prepareForSegue method from preceding view controller.

Answer (score 4):

This method definitely works. You just need to put it in the method BEFORE you push it, like this:

```
-actionThatPushTheViewController { 

    //create the view controller here, do some init. 

    //then:
    theViewControllerToBePushed.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

    //push it here like this: 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:theViewControllerToBePushed animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this two methods may help you,

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

int height = 480;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
    } 
    else {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,view.frame.origin.y, 320, 436)];
    }
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

```
- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

int height = 480;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; 

for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews) {

    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];            
    } 
    else {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, height)];
    }
}    

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

Just put this two methods in AppDelegate class and call it where ever required as per you requirement.

Comment: i dont want to change the frame size of the subviews.. when popped, it pops to another view altogether.. subviews are also gone

Comment: Seems to be working well, I added some adjustments to handle both iPhone and iPad. I get width and height of the window like so

float height = self.window.frame.size.height;
float width = self.window.frame.size.width;

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide it when pushed and show it when popped here is code:

```
if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC {
    if let navigator = navigationController {
        viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```